# bind_result failed

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I actually tried `mysqli->fetch_array();` for fetching array but that couldn't work so I used bind_result(); and it throws the below error

`Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

So I did a error check on bind_result and what I got was `bind_result() failed:` so what I am really doing wrong?

```
$wtf = "";
$hello = "";
$check_empty_field = $mysqli - > prepare("select `username`, `firstname`, `lastname` from `vpb_uploads` where `username` = ?  and `firstname` = ? and `lastname` = ?");
$check_empty_field - > bind_param('sss', $username, $wtf, $hello);
$check_empty_field - > execute();
$check_empty_field - > store_result();
if($check_empty_field - > num_rows < 1) {
  $date = date("d-m-Y");
  $i2 = '';
  $i3 = '';
  $i4 = '';
  $i5 = '';
  $insert = $mysqli - > prepare("insert into `vpb_uploads` (`username`, `firstname`, `lastname`, image_one, image_two, image_three, image_four, image_five, date)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $insert - > bind_param('sssssssss', $username, $wtf, $hello, $random_name_generated, $i2, $i3, $i4, $i5, $date);
  $insert - > execute();
  $identity = "image_one";
} else {
  $get_empty_field = $check_empty_field - > bind_result($username, $wtf, $hello);
  if(false === $get_empty_field) {
    die('bind_result() failed: '.htmlspecialchars($mysqli - > error));
  }
  $image_one = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_one"]);
  $image_two = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_two"]);
  $image_three = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_three"]);
  $image_four = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_four"]);
  $image_five = strip_tags($get_empty_field["image_five"]);
  global $identity;
}
```

Comment: You're not including all the relevant code, where is `$stmt` initialised?  Also does `- >` really work with those extra spaces?

Comment: @therefromhere sorry that was typo.

Comment: Also, was `$username` defined?  (though I don't think that's the bug)

Comment: @therefromhere yes it is defined

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because you have not set each of the column names which are returned from the SQL query to a variable.

Example:

If you have 6 columns in your table and you have selected all (*) then you will have to:

```
$stmt->bind_result($Col_1,$Col_2,$Col_3,$Col_4,$Col_5,$Col_6);
```

If you have:

```
$stmt->bind_result($Col_1,$Col_2,$Col_3,$Col_4,$Col_5);
```

an error will be thrown.

---

```
$check_empty_field->data_seek(0);
  $get_empty_field = $check_empty_field - > bind_result($username, $wtf, $hello);
```

Comment: the error is gone but the query is inserting all the image to one col instead it inserts each image to a new col

Comment: Then you will have to echo out the variables you are inserting making sure that they are populated correctly

Comment: you know what I changed just $check_empty_field and $get_empty_field query to mysql and it works fine. There is no problem with the insert query. The problem lies on those two queries